# Prevent word doc from opening in read-only, compile error

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working with an Excel model that pulls a word document from a website and opens it up, and I am trying to insert a line of code to ensure that the document doesn't open in read-only view. Specifically, there is an error that is happening when users have the "Open email attachements and other uneditable files in reading view" checked, which appears when you click on file -> options on the word document. So I am trying to make sure this box is unchecked when it opens the word doc. I did some research and the line
"ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = False"
seems like it should work, however I am getting an error message that says "Compile Error: Invalid Qualifier" that highlights the line I just added. The rest of the code was not written by me and can't be changed. Is there any way I can do this?
This is a snipped of the code.

```
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("https://WebsiteRedacted")
'Opens up the template

objWord.Visible = True

ActiveWindow.View.readinglaout = False
'The line I added in
```

Comment: Excel has an `ActiveWindow` object. You want to work with the Word instance's window (assuming that `.View.ReadingLayout = False` will achieve the end result, not sure).

Comment: Try using `Documents.Add` instead of `Documents.Open`

Comment: @braX I tried this, and still got the error. .View is highlighted with the error message, so I think it might be something to do with that

Comment: @BigBen What is Word instance's window? Is that a change I would make instead of the ActiveWindow part of the code? Thanks

Comment: `objWord.ActiveWindow` refers to the window in Word. `ActiveWindow` alone is implicitly `Application.ActiveWindow`, referring to Excel (`Application`) instead of the instance of Word.

Comment: is it really called `readinglaout` or is it supposed to be `readinglayout` ?